# jQuery click Class load a link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script in wordpress installed that adds a selected video to favorite. The code is like this : when a user clicks on a button the script send a request like "?wpfpaction=add&postid=147" and i have the id of video like this

```
<div class="wrap-box-video" id="424">
   <div class="button_fav">
     <a href="?wpfpaction=add&postid=424" rel=nofollow"><img src="blabla" /></a>
   </div>
</div>
```

It is possible to make a jQuery that instead of "button_fav" let's say i have "addfav" and "removefav" (I have to code that echo the "addfav" if the video isn't added to favorite or "removefav" if the video exists at favorite) when a user clicks on the div with class "addfav"/"removefav" the jQuery extracts id from the class="wrap-box-video" and send the href "`?wpfpaction=add&postid=424`" ?

I managed to make it work with this code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){ $("div.addfav").click(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); alert(window.location.href.split('?')[0] + "?wpfpaction=add&postid=" + $(this).parents(".wrap-box-video").attr("id")); }); }
```

My problem is now, how to make this work because this gives me only a Alert and if I delete the "alert()" isn't working, I want this to load and not show in url ( not showing the ?wpfaction.... after the url)

Comment: close your ``a``'s first! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the final HTML will be something like this :

```
<div class="wrap-box-video" id="424">
   <div class="addfav">
       <a href="?wpfpaction=add&postid=424" rel="nofollow"><img src="blabla" alt="add" /></a>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="wrap-box-video" id="425">
   <div class="removefav">
     <a href="?wpfpaction=add&postid=424" rel="nofollow"><img src="blabla" alt="remove" /></a>
   </div>
</div>
```

jQuery for creating dynamic URL :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div.wrap-box-video a").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if($(this).parent().hasClass('addfav'))
        {
            alert(window.location.href.split('?')[0] + "?wpfpaction=add&postid=" + $(this).parents('div.wrap-box-video').first().attr("id"));
        }
        else
        {
            alert(window.location.href.split('?')[0] + "?wpfpaction=remove&postid=" + $(this).parents('div.wrap-box-video').first().attr("id"));
        }
    });
});
```

It assumes that your remove URL will be "wpfpaction=remove&postid=424"

[**JS FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ankitsnghn/b17uqtdh/)

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div.addfav").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
       alert(window.location.href.split('?')[0] + "?wpfpaction=add&postid=" + $(this).parents(".wrap-box-video").attr("id"));
    });
}` this works good it shows the alert.. but how can i make it load in the url ? to make it work...

Comment: Hey @user3469760, just use this instead of the alert : `document.location.href = window.location.href.split('?')[0] + "?wpfpaction=add&postid=" + $(this).parents('div.wrap-box-video').first().attr("id");`   Updated [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ankitsnghn/b17uqtdh/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Yup. Given

```
<div class="wrap-box-video" id="424">
   <div class="button_fav">
     <a href="?wpfpaction=add&postid=424" rel=nofollow"><img src="blabla" /></a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Using jQuery your code would be something like:

```
$(".button_fav").on('click', function() {
  var id = $(this).closest('.wrap-box-video')[0].id;
  window.location = "?wpfpaction=add&postid="+id;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of ways you can do that, but the easiest way is probably to use the HTML data element  (i.e. `data-id="yourIdNumber"` then put something like this in your click event - `$(this).closest('.wrap-box-video').data('id');`

Answer (score 0):

This may work;

```
$('.button_fav').click(
    function(){
        var myHref = $(this).children("a").attr('href');
         var videoId = $(this).parents(".wrap-box-video").attr("id");
    }
);
```